# RSpec 3 - deprecated "Should"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

If `should` is deprecated, I do not want to enable it's usage.  What is the new `expect` syntax for this?

```
   describe '#show response' do 
        it "should return html data only" do 
          get :show, params: {:id => "bike"}
          response.header['Content-Type'].should include 'text/html'
        end

        it "should not return json data" do 
          get :show, params: {:id => "bike"}
          response.header['Content-Type'].should_not include 'application/json'
        end

        it "should not return js data" do 
          get :show, params: {:id => "bike"}
          response.header['Content-Type'].should_not include 'text/javascript'
        end
      end
    end
```

Deprecation Warnings:

> Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without
>   explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect`
>   syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec)
>   { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead.

Comment: Rspec has fantastic documentation and expect syntax has been the default for quite a while now. For instance you are looking for the [include matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher)

Comment: RSpec 3, not Rails!, encouraged users to use the new expect syntax - as explained in the blog post. _RSpec 3 print a warning on first usage of any the old syntax methods_ ... _unless the should syntax has been explicitly enabled._ http://rspec.info/blog/2013/07/the-plan-for-rspec-3/

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `expect().to be()`, so in your case:

```
expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include('text/html')
expect(response.header['Content-Type']).not_to include('application/json')
expect(response.header['Content-Type']).not_to include('text/javascript')
```

More info on `rspec` matchers here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

Comment: It would actually be more like `expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include( 'text/html'`)` and obviously the inversion is `not_to include`